# Using params in a sqlite INSERT statement in Smart Mobile Studio?

Tags: smart-mobile-studio

I have created the following database

```
SqlResult := fDataBase.Exec("CREATE TABLE workstations (workstation string, location string, userId string);");
```

How do you use params in a sqlite INSERT statement.

For example, I assume it would be something as such

```
FDatabase.Exec("INSERT INTO workstations values(?,?,?);", [AWorkstation, ALocation, AUserId]);
```

However, Exec only takes a string........so do I have to actually build out the whole string to include the params?

```
FDatabase.Exec("INSERT INTO workstations values( + AWorkstation + ',' + ALocation + ',' +  AUserId +');" );
```

reason I ask, is that the

TSQLiteDatabase  has a CreateStatement function that returns a

TSQLiteStatement  class

which has a SQL & Params property

and the following methods

prepare
execute
release

do I instead of calling the databases exec, i instead do a createstatement, assign sql and params, and then execute ?

e.g.

```
stm:= fDatabase.CreateStatement;
stm.SQL:= ?
stm.Params:=  ?
stm.execute;
```

i have even tried

```
FDatabase.Exec('INSERT INTO workstations (workstation, location, userid) values(' + AWorkstation + ',' + ALocation + ',' +  AUserId +');');
```

If I hardcode the values, this works

```
FDatabase.Exec("INSERT INTO workstations (workstation, location, userid) values('WS0202', 'Maintenance', 'jdoe');");
```

but, i need to be able to use params

also tried it with a format function and still doesn't work

```
FDatabase.Exec(Format("INSERT INTO workstations (workstation, location, userid) values(%s ,%s, %s );", [AWorkstation, ALocation, AUserId]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FDatabase.Exec(Format("INSERT INTO workstations (workstation, location, userid) values('%s' ,'%s', '%s');", [AWorkstation, ALocation, AUserId]));
```